# python counting occurrences value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, count, nested

I am stuck with unable to find a solution to count value.

```
data = {"members": {
    "1": {
        "name": "burek",            
        },
        "status": {
            "description": "Online",
            "state": "Busy",
            "color": "green",
        },
        "position": "seller"
    },{
    "2": {
        "name": "pica",         
        },
        "status": {
            "description": "Offline",
            "state": "Idle",
            "color": "red",
        },
        "position": "waiting"
    },{
    "3": {
        "name": "strucko",          
        },
        "status": {
            "description": "Online",
            "state": "Busy",
            "color": "green",
        },
        "position": "backside"
    }}
```

Now I can count the keys:

```
def count(d, k):
 return (k in d) + sum(count(v, k) for v in d.values() if isinstance(v, dict))
```

But have a lot of trouble figuring out ways to count the value.

```
print(count(data, 'Online'))
```

I want the result to be 2.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please [edit] to add your best attempt. If this is homework, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Apparently `data` is not valid. I'm getting a SyntaxError at the comma in line 21, though I haven't found the problem yet.

Comment: @wjandrea added the one I used for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach:

```
def count(d, k):
    current = 0
    for di in d.values():
        if isinstance(di, dict):
            current += count(di, k)
        elif k == di:
            current += 1
    return current


res = count(data, "Online")
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
2
```

**Setup**

```
data = {
  "members": {
    "1": {
      "name": "burek",
      "status": {
        "description": "Online",
        "state": "Busy",
        "color": "green"
      },
      "position": "seller"
    },
    "2": {
      "name": "pica",
      "status": {
        "description": "Offline",
        "state": "Idle",
        "color": "red"
      },
      "position": "waiting"
    },
    "3": {
      "name": "strucko",
      "status": {
        "description": "Online",
        "state": "Busy",
        "color": "green"
      },
      "position": "backside"
    }
  }
}
```